# Iterating through every list in a dictionary of lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary of lists. 
For every list in the dictionary I nedd to apply the following code:

```
list = [1,4,2,6,5,8,3,9]

x = 0
y = 1

for v in range(len(list)):
    if list[x] <= 3 and list[y] >=3:
        print(list[y])
    x = x + 1
    y = y + 1
```

The code above is a example that works applied to one list.
I need this working for all the lists in a dictionary. 
I have tried the following:

```
res = {1: [10, 20, 30, 20], 2: [30, 70, 30, 10], 4: [5, 40, 50, 10, 50, 40, 80]}
x=1
y=0
z=1
for key in res:
    if key == x :
        for value in range(len(res[x]):
            if res[1][y] <= 20 and res[1][z] >=20:
                print (res[x][z])
            x=x+1
            y=y+1
            z=z+1
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Since this seems to be your first post, please read the [tour] and [ask]. Then, can you describe what you want to achieve in little bit more words instead of code? That makes it easier for anyone to answer the question :-)

Answer (score 1):

I actually don't understand what you are trying to acomplish here but you can iterate over dictionary items for key value pair.

```
for key, value in res.items()
    # do your stuff with key and value.
```